# Using concat function in MySql in a shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I have the following script which fetches employee id from Employee table in every database allocated to the employee and alters the EmployeeLedger_$empId table in the corresponding database

```
cls_ip="localhost";

mysql="mysql -h $cls_ip -u root"
list=`echo "show databases like '$dbPattern'" | $mysql| grep -v Database`

for db in $list
do
    echo "altering EmployeeLedger table for database $db";
    ${mysql} ${db} -e "use $db";
    empId=`${mysql} ${db} -e "select EMPID from Employee"`;
    echo "$empId";
    ${mysql} ${db} -e "alter table concat('EmpTimeLedger',$empId) add column HOLIDAY tinyint(1) not null default 1;";
done
```

Here I am unsuccessful in concatenating the employee id which i retrieve from Employee table with EmplyeeLedger to form EmployeeLedger_$empId table. How do i do it?

Comment: Why don't you just do like this `empId="EmpTimeLedger_$empId";` and then `"ALTER TABLE $empId ADD COLUMN ..."`?

Comment: @Cyclone That one did the trick!! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, too bad I didn't added it as an answer =)

Comment: @Cyclone Please add it as answer so that i can mark it as right

Comment: I added my comment as an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to simply concatenate the `empId` to the name of your table:

```
table="EmpTimeLedger_$empId";
```

Then you would alter your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE $table
ADD COLUMN HOLIDAY TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try manual string concatenation like this

foo="EmpTimeLedger"
foo+=$empId

${mysql} ${db} -e "alter table $foo add column HOLIDAY tinyint(1) not null default 1;"